# Why is EU so prolific with its regulations?

Tags: european-union, regulation

There seems to be a broad eurosceptic mood across Europe. 
Much of the anger at the EU is expressed in frustration at various EU regulations.

There seems to be a risk of disintegration of the EU. 
If the EU produced fewer regulations it could lower this risk.
Why doesn't EU produce fewer regulations in an attempt reduce the Eurosceptic mood in Europe?

Comment: The EU creates many regulations, yes. But I doubt that most member states would create a smaller number of regulations without the EU. Note that the member states have a strong influence on the regulations, a fact national politicians conveniently forget if a regulation turns out to be unpopular.

Comment: @Roland I agree that member states produce likely the same or even greater volume of regulations. But they are states and their integrity is not questionable while EU is not yet a state and IMHO should probably adopt a more cautious and pragmatic policy.

Comment: You underestimate the advantages the harmonized European regulations bring to us.

Comment: @Roland I'm not talking whether they are good or bad, but looks like most of the regulations are not well timed. It seems like there is a missing institution in the EU that would assess impact of acts to the stability in EU.

Comment: EU regulations typically revolve around health and environment issues such as [plastic waste](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32011R0010). The more, the better. And if you disagree, please go live some place where businesses can screw with your health for a profit.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Again I'm not assessing here the regulations (although some of them raise many questions: length of bananas, forbidding of national traditional names for butter, etc.). I would agree that most of them will likely bring benefits, but their amount and the speed of affecting people's everyday life is enormous. People don't manage to understand their long-term advantages, while there are more and more new restrictions issuing. I'm not an eurosceptic, but I see how people around are getting frustrated about EU and want to understand why it doesn't try to calm the situation.

Comment: The "banana length/curve regulation" has long since been debunked @DmitryDruganov. It is simply a method of classification that most countries already had. At any rate, after editing the question seems like a good one, so voted to re-open.

Comment: "If the EU produced fewer regulations it could lower this risk." Do you have any supporting evidence for this claim?

Comment: This sounds a bit like the question "Why doesn't the EU cease its activities to make the people forget that it exists?"

Comment: I would suggest there are two factors that are equally bad when it comes to EU skepticism: the EU is also expensive and quite bad at enforcing its own rules.

Answer (score 8):

The EU isn't prolific with regulations. Most of the regulations it passes already exist in member states, and the EU is just harmonizing them across the continent.

The classic example of this is the "straight bananas" myth. The rules were already in effect in the UK and most other EU countries, because they were an international de-facto standard used by banana producers and banana consumers. When the EU harmonized nothing actually changed in the UK - no new laws, no changes to standard or regulations, nothing. But what were once UK rules suddenly had an EU stamp on them, and were branded as silly and excessive.

This also illustrates the difficulty in determining what is an EU regulation. Given that the UK already had the same rules anyway, do rules covering bananas count as EU regs?

Based on a BBC investigation of the issue, the amount of UK law that is derived from EU regulations could be as low as 13%.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-eu-referendum-36473105

Comment: ` the amount of UK law that is derived from EU regulations could be as low as 13%.` This doesn't matter, as it's which laws affect your daily life most often, not which laws exists, which counts the most. Those 13% of laws you're talking about could be 90% of 1% of those who matters in daily life.